# Is there any way to schedule software update?

Tags: software-update

I have software updates set to check weekly, but it seems to happen at random times during the day. I'd really like to have it run at a specific day and time - say 4:30 on Friday - so that I can just let it run on my way out the door, rather than having to let the computer restart in the middle of a workday. Is it possible to schedule the software update that granularly? Obviously it can't be done via system prefs, but maybe there's a hidden setting somewhere (or a utility I can download) that I'm not aware of as a Mac newb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you goto the Software Update preferences, you can set it to daily, monthly or weekly. Obviously, this a very basic update scheduler. If you want to update weekly at this time just goto preferences and select weekly, now.

You can also do it using an Apple script + softwareupdater as described [here](http://www.tuaw.com/2010/01/10/manually-schedule-software-update-the-os-x-way-with-launchd/).

Comment: As I said I already have it set to weekly. I'm looking for more specific control over the day and time. Thanks for the link; I'll look at the link when I have a few minutes to process it - I've never worked with AppleScript.

Comment: I just read the article and set up an agent using Lingon as suggested. Simple and easy; just need to see if it actually runs tomorrow! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Emmy - if you want to automate this without a user approving the changes, see this thread. [How to silently update OS X and reboot if necesary?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14072/how-to-silently-update-os-x-and-reboot-if-necesary)

Otherwise just use iCal to schedule and set an alarm to open the file

```
/System/Library/Core Services/Software Update.app
```

as shown below:
[image: iCal alarms]

There are tons of ways to script this, but iCal is really simple for this task.

Answer (score 1):

You can automate this by date and time using 'launchd'
here's an [article](http://www.tuaw.com/2010/01/10/manually-schedule-software-update-the-os-x-way-with-launchd/) about it. Note: This will download the updates in the background automatically, you won't see the apple software update window. So you won't have to push any confirm to install buttons.