# How to schedule Mac software updates at a particular time in Yosemite?

Tags: macos, software-update, software

I saw [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14467/is-there-any-way-to-schedule-software-update/14470?s=2%7C0.1432#14470) helpful answer, but cannot find the Software Update.app file when I search for it on my Mac (Yosemite) to insert it into the iCal event.

So how can I schedule software updates on Yosemite?

Comment: In Yosemite, the path specified in the helpful answer is correct: `/System/Library/CoreServices/Software Update.app`. I don't have iCal to test this, and Calendar.app doesn't seem to have the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

How are you searching for it?  If in **Spotlight**, don't. The **Software Update.app** bundle is exactly where the reference states that is it!  Its fully qualified pathname is `/System/Library/CoreServices/Software Update.app` and you can see it in **Finder** by starting in the **root** of the **Macintosh HD** or if in **iCal** when selecting the file to open, make sure you start navigating to it from the **root** of the **Macintosh HD** (or whatever the name of your HD is).

Comment: and another + from me for precise answer.